# vim install from source fails in macOS high sierra

Tags: vim, macos-high-sierra

I recently upgraded from 10.9 to 10.13 and had to reinstall vim. I checked out vim from source and did the following:

```
$/source-pkgs/vim>./configure --with-features=huge -
-enable-multibyte --enable-rubyinterp=yes --enable-pythoninterp=yes --with-
python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config --enable-cscope --
prefix=/usr/local
configure: loading cache auto/config.cache
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/arenduchintala/source-pkgs/vim/src':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

To make matters worse I can't seem to locate `config.log`!! It does not appear in `$:source-pkgs/vim` or anywhere in `/usr/local/`
My gcc seems to work fine:

```
$/source-pkgs/vim>which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$/source-pkgs/vim>gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed would be helpful!

Comment: Sorry to digress from your question, but I'm curious why build source manually instead of installing with something like Homebrew (https://brew.sh/)

Comment: Is there a `config.log` in `~/source-pkgs/vim/src`?